# Boost SML: respond to determination made in action

Tags: c++, c++14, state-machine, boost-extension, boost-sml

I am trying to use a Boost SML state machine to implement a "receiver". As an example, lets say the SM receives ints and is "done" when it gets to a certain number:

- An "idle" state moves to a "reading" state on a "receive" event, accumulate the received data
- If the limit is reached, terminate, or else keep reading

I have done this so far with a guard, `gNotDone`, which returns true if the capacity is not reached.

And then while reading, having passed the guard, actually process the data in the `aReceive` action.

```
#include <boost/sml.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace sml = boost::sml;

namespace {
struct eReceive {
    int data;
};

struct sIdle{};
struct sReading{};

struct Context {

    Context(const std::string& name, unsigned capacity):
        name(name),
        received(0),
        capacity(capacity) {
    }

    std::string name;
    unsigned received;
    unsigned capacity;
};

struct SM {
    auto operator()() const noexcept {
        using namespace sml;

        const auto gNotDone = [this] (const Context& ctx) -> bool {
            return ctx.received < ctx.capacity;
        };

        const auto aReceive = [this] (const eReceive& e, Context& ctx) {
            ctx.received += e.data;
            std::cout << "Received " << e.data << ", so far: " << ctx.received << std::endl;
        };

        const auto aDone = [] {
            std::cout << "Done (reach capacity)" << std::endl;
        };

        // clang-format off
        return make_transition_table(
                // Start reading
               *state<sIdle>        + event<eReceive> [gNotDone] / aReceive     = state<sReading>
               // Keeps reading until "done"
            ,   state<sReading>     + event<eReceive> [gNotDone] / aReceive
            ,   state<sReading>     + event<eReceive> / aDone                = X
        );
        // clang-format on
    }
};
}  // namespace

int main() {

    Context theContext("The context", 30);
    sml::sm<SM> sm{theContext};

    sm.process_event(eReceive{11});
    sm.process_event(eReceive{22});
}
```

[Try it here.](https://cpp.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXAOx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEs6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEEgCspAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcVyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BXAFVNQJ1DQRFEdGxCbb1jc05bcM9fSVlCQCUtqhexMjsHAD06yYaAIKbANQeSQCexHjACAT7EMhz%2B2YaXABsALQPD/sA0mcK%2BwBSXjSTAA1tdgT99kwrtpAXgQft0KgrmECHNtnstrsDgARPAKAhnKJeAiYdD7LwMLDEfYEBCYfYWVCpK5CVBUAgAdwa9JCqwYSlI%2BwAarE0gJ9lwAHQaSXog4QISYelMZBoFhJQzHULAfY0ej7IIASTc2HCQmwAH0uBaZQRVFcSPs0CdIQQ5et9pcCEkQJsOf7JVEmfjJSRgOsjSazZbrbb7WisZiduYAMyhZDeLD7cxmL1JBS%2B9bEJgcyXAQgILxEpQrWSMAiStXrIPMl6Ye3rBQsWjrFhMfGxdbpzOYZvBgid7uShBJJI59ELsxphgZrxZkwptxOfHETCsDfYBe7dHMNgKDWrfZd2jZlPY/Yt/EgEDXjdWY%2B7U%2BYc8q%2BkmSTvjsO5eA4%2ByYAAStUmB4AAbn%2BAHovsSH7KEVzoFCTBvgukjYlhH5AQSIFXAohroPQ/5WDheEEcQRFXpBTD4EYFH/rhKaAeiwGgR4gjtlcLH4chhx1vaNwCPiV4EOgz47tq5hPPsX6ChSaTAGEZKiBehDHHMICIUJyFfhAX4LPpBn7LuqywaSEAaKZuzmUhmkqtpNxMFpBA6dmCEOchrFHjsQn4tJL4EtqimsJg1FCSp5zqRZUHWeg0XIbFamkk67kuZ51H%2BexAVcSyACy3mAUJTDEqg%2ByoEksRQiQEBzI1TriciqDtqsST8T5gWObCRgRWeF70q%2B%2BWCY5aD8lcFVEPswDhEi2ICH%2Bd7ZvEVjxPeYlTcJvH2vJTp2ncLwHg%2BTI3gJvWOchu4EMsDCHaokqWdBcFkhubiPY2WXINpKXmXlHG%2BeZk0STNVVMJBVlwbe94mOt8NbaDVwQYlcEHZggo8SS%2B1mApDiqHcl3XUJBPPWjGXWBu96YJK6H1P9JPBc%2BaDErebgfdmZhmFDr2U9z7Oc7T9NMILm5cwEV5VVQDQgBLYufWTL1JQrkkha4tCM0JgMBddyOQpVkJLWEsNrRtcM9STyHMygSz8ZunM5sb9IQLuKoIJlHk6Tmqs2xrWt%2BVRY3JsDBkHBmhjAC8/DEH2DpUFQZkGbd937H2wKYBaBKGGkjgCFnTBRPQEBJ1bSEHN0jQJYxcmh2XABU%2BJQlFm4kWRLfYNd1hgXBggfaj0Md2b82LctiP7B6kMUwZ1OSc3H0KAxTHAAepdWwcnxKvm1fL%2BSgh0BLiJhPOdeOYKSFNySC9L3JKad9rlg9/W/e89Zp3wxYI8EM74%2BT6/6On3MufOeV9W432YnfGej9MC9zdJuAefNTqT2dmXGeq0AAaa8kJomDtdcOBgjDRxIHHaqDAk7%2BWPEHDiOFy4ei/D%2BVYAVUJpyYKEZql0k7Yz4jSOkXDRI5gACp0hantN03NBQpjsoza8MkWAfSEEVU6XYKK0kwHwt0VDdbWxYJKJIxBUCrAUAoC0MD6wQAQW/ACXAuCsRwWVbRuj9GGOMaYwQ5j/5RQAtzWxuUcIcAWLQTg8ReB%2BA4FoUgqBOAc0sN3BQSwVh/iXDwUgBBND%2BIWMCEA8QpQAE5Hg5IACwFIeDkp4KYnjxACIEjgBSQlpIiZwXgBYNApLSQsOAsAYCIFtuqOgsRyCUDVEkPpcQI5GC4JIlpeoSTEALBAKI9SoihAaMcTgyS1RsEEAAeQYLQVZYTeBYD7EYcQBzSD4Eso4OCBYzntmqMSNY4TUKYGqeE2geAojFmIMcDwWB6lhRYGs/xfADDAAUEKPAmAORbNqqE5J/BBAiDEOwLgBSZCCEUCodQZzdBcH0JHFAVNLD6A%2BQWSACwap535JwF4WzfgvGCtTUwMTLBSH2C8AA6mIG8nK%2BLFiaS86oVKXCUjGK0QIlJpgDHKHkXOGQxV6BSHKwooR%2BilEGHijoVLK5NE8C0PQWragjF6KqmYGrJijD1eMC1JrijSokAsOJyxVh6AJEqIFASgl1LOZEjgqgAAcrwngFKdAQnUEzpTSmuNEqwxL9i4EII6VMeLhK9PoNSZNcxeCpIOXMDJWSWnVNqaQQF8QWmhPCb6ppIAWk5q0O0rpEAkB2ySMSAZ5j8BEDONJPFCLhCiHEBM9F8glBqHqbi0gHJiw%2Bm4MC6pwTSAVt4L6rZxJW3x32AGoNIaxnhpTJGjQ0bUBptiFzFMXAs2tNzQsOkjFBiNX0JwYtpby31KrbYGtV7635oKf66UOT/UaHiPESQeTykpl/Y%2BjgKZvWVsaV%2B9JUGzCweXfButiG4KzIyCAApQA)

```
Received 11, so far: 11
Received 22, so far: 33
```

However, I don't feel this is quite right: it feels like the next state should somehow be determined by the `aReceive` action - if the limit was passed, move into the terminal state.

As it is, you'll only move into the terminal state after the *next* receive event.

It also doesn't feel right to "test" in guards if the event will pass the limit as this probably entails repeating the calculation (it's just a sum here, but it could be expensive).

What is the standard way in an SML state machine to decide the *next* state based on what happened with an event in the *current* state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your state machine can described as follows:

[image: UML Statemachine DIagram]

sml doesn't support `choice puseudo state` (rhombus shape in the diagram) but we can use "normal" state instead.

The diagram use if/else branch from the `choice pseudo state`. But it doesn't supported in sml.

So I define `gDone` and `gNotDone`. It is the similar as defining `==` and `!=` operators for the C++ class.

The code is updated as follows:

```cpp
struct eReceive {
    int data;
};

struct sReading{};
// choice pseudo state (UML 2.x)
// sml doesn't support choice pseudo state directly
// but we can use (normal) state.
struct psChoice{}; 

struct Context {

    Context(const std::string& name, unsigned capacity):
        name(name),
        received(0),
        capacity(capacity) {
    }

    std::string name;
    unsigned received;
    unsigned capacity;
};

//              eReceive/aReceive           [gDone]/aDone
// *-->sReading------------------->psChoice--------------->X
//         A                         |
//         |                         | [else] (=gNotDone)
//         |                         |
//         +-------------------------+                            
//
struct SM {
    auto operator()() const noexcept {
        using namespace sml;

        const auto gDone = [] (const Context& ctx) -> bool {
            return ctx.received >= ctx.capacity;
        };
        // sml doesn't support "else" guard. So I define it.
        const auto gNotDone = [gDone] (const Context& ctx) -> bool {
            return !gDone(ctx);
        };

        const auto aReceive = [] (const eReceive& e, Context& ctx) {
            ctx.received += e.data;
            std::cout << "Received " << e.data << ", so far: " << ctx.received << std::endl;
        };

        const auto aDone = [] {
            std::cout << "Done (reach capacity)" << std::endl;
        };

        // clang-format off
        return make_transition_table(
                // From state      Event           Guard       Action     To state
               *state<sReading>  + event<eReceive>           / aReceive = state<psChoice>
            ,   state<psChoice>                   [gNotDone]            = state<sReading>
            ,   state<psChoice>                   [gDone   ] / aDone    = X
        );
        // clang-format on
    }
};
```

All code is at https://cpp.godbolt.org/z/Mc9nYzMcr

Comment: Looks like the primary thing I was missing was that you can have so-called "anonymous transitions", which traverse immediately without further events. For example `state<psChoice> [gDone] = X`. Thank you!

Comment: Also it seems you can negate a guard with the `!` operator (since the guard returns `bool`): `state<S> [!gGuard] ...`. E.g. https://cpp.godbolt.org/z/7GnhKzr7v